# WPF Grid allow controls inside to auto size width/height

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, resize, autosize

Hey all i have been trying to find examples of how to go about auto sizing the controls i have within a grid control if the users screen is larger than the default size.

Currently i am unable to resize the controls when i enlarge the form. Is there any code currently that can find all controls inside the grid and resize them on the fly when the form is resized?

My current code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="768" Width="1024">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="115" Margin="190,0,195,145" Name="Grid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Cyan">
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Button4" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,10,0,0" Name="Button5" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,10,0,0" Name="Button6" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="280,10,257,0" Name="Button7" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,166,0" Name="Button8" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,75,0" Name="Button9" VerticalAlignment="Top">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,9" Name="Button10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,0,0,9" Name="Button11" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,0,0,9" Name="Button12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="280,0,257,9" Name="Button13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,166,9" Name="Button14" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
            <Button Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,75,9" Name="Button15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Button</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Probably all you need is an `UniformGrid` with two rows and a Button style for Margin.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you aren't using the grid in the way it was intended.

If you want your UI to dynamically resize with the window, you shouldn't have any (or at least minimize) the number of hard coded widths and heights. The first problem I see is that the inner grid has a hard coded height of 127, so regardless of the size of the window that grid will always be that height. Removing that height is a good first step.

I'm also not sure why there are two grids - couldn't all of the buttons just be children of the outer grid?

Finally, you aren't defining any rows or columns in the grid. I think you were trying to use the `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties on the individual buttons to control where they are on the window. It is much better to define rows and columns based on where you want the buttons to be. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) has an example of how to use a grid with multiple rows and columns.

Comment: Alright i updated the OP with some changes in code. But it still does not re-size when i make the form larger. The grid does re-size to a larger grid but not the buttons.

Comment: @StealthRT Did you try defining rows and columns, and assigning the buttons to them?

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't give me any visible lines? **<Grid Height="115" Margin="190,0,195,145" Name="Grid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="10">**

Comment: @StealthRT The purpose of the grid isn't to displays cells with borders like a spreadsheet, but rather to control complex layouts. You can use the `ShowGridLines` property to display the cell borders if you want, though.